# How can I plot a standing wave that decay with the time ?

Tags: plotting

How can I plot a standing wave that decay with the time ?

[image: something like this]

Comment: Do you have a functional form to plot?  Is this a Mathematica question?

Answer (score 7):

Parameters:

```
γ = 0.4;
ω = 2 Pi;
```

Set up the standard differential equation for a Damped Harmonic Oscillation:

```
s = NDSolve[{x''[t] + 2 γ x'[t] + ω^2 x[t] == 0, 
   x[0] == 5, x'[0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, 12}]
```

Plot

```
Plot[x[t] /. s, {t, 0, 12}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {t, A}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**  There is an analytic solution for the general equation.

```
Clear[γ, ω]

eqns = {x''[t] + 2 γ x'[t] + ω^2 x[t] == 0, x[0] == 5, 
   x'[0] == 0};

s = DSolve[eqns, x, {t, 0, 12}][[1]]
```

[image]

Verifying the solution

```
eqns /. s // Simplify

(*  {True, True, True}  *)
```

The plot is as before

```
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. s /. {γ -> 2/5, ω -> 2 Pi}],
 {t, 0, 12}, PlotRange -> All,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 14] & /@ {"t", "A"})]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Solution can be further simplified to the more recognizable form, with `Ω` the reduced angular frequency.

```
so = ExpandAll[Refine[x[t] /. s /. γ^2 -> ω^2 - Ω^2, Ω > 0]]

sol = so /. E^(a_ + (I | -I) b_) :> E^a (Cos[b] + I Sin[b]) // Expand

sol[[1]] (* real part *)
```

> `5 E^(-t γ) Cos[t Ω]`